# Setting up Exponential growth function X = a(1+b)^t in C language

Tags: c, exponential, pow, math.h

I'm writing a program to track the number of rectangles being made in one week using the exponential growth function (X = a(1+b)^t). One person can make 60 rectangles per day.

a represents the initial population, this is the number of people already making rectangles on the first of the week. b represents the growth rate, this is the number of new people making rectangles each day. t represents the time interval, which is 7 days for this program.

I'm having difficulties getting started with the problem, and I need some guidance please.

I was thinking using using math.h and pow, something like this (this code is not compiling)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {

    int initial_POPULATION;
    int time_INTERVAL; 
    double growth_RATE;

    printf("How many people are making rectangles at the 
    biginning of the week?\n");
    scanf("%d", &initial_POPULATION);

    printf("How many people are making rectangles each day? 
    \n");
    scanf("%1f", &growth_RATE);

    //Exponential growth function X = a(1+b)^t
    printf("%d rectangles will be made this week!\n",
        initial_POPULATION(pow(1+growth_RATE),time_INTERVAL));

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: what is this doing: `initial_POPULATION(pow(1+growth_RATE),time_INTERVAL))` ?

Comment: I wonder why this is modeled exponentially. Are the people who make rectangles also made of rectangles?

Comment: I was trying to put the exponential growth equation in there to get  the result of how many rectangles will be made.  xD @Z4-tier

Comment: Yeah... the rate kf increase in number of persons making rectangles would have to be proportional to the number of persons...?

Comment: a represents the initial population, this is the number of people already making rectangles on the first of the week. b represents the growth rate, this is the number of new people making rectangles each day. t represents the time interval, which is 7 days for this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple problems, but the most apparent is that you are not setting the value of `time_INTERVAL` anywhere. Next is the line where the final value is calculated: in C, you need to use `*` to denote multiplication. Parens do not work as implied multiplication operators like in regular math (at any rate, the way the parenthesis are being used in the last `printf` is not right). Finally, make sure to read `growth_RATE` as a double by using `%lf` as the format specifier in `scanf` (using `%f` reads it as a single precision 4-byte value, even though it's declared as a double which is... well, double that).

Try this:

```
    scanf("%lf", &growth_RATE);
    time_INTERVAL=7;
    printf("%f rectangles will be made this week!\n", initial_POPULATION * pow(1+growth_RATE, time_INTERVAL));
```

Also, as mentioned by @Asadefa, remove the line breaks from the string literals.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. I have made the advised changes plus the correction, and now the program does compile, but when I run the program I get  -1.#INF00 as a result.

Comment: Thank you again, I made the changes and I'm getting the expected result when I use integers, but when I enter a decimal for the growth_RATE I get the -1.#INF00

Comment: sorry, my last comment had a typo. use this: `scanf("%lf", &growth_RATE);`

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 possible reasons your code isn't compiling.

Did you try compiling like this if you're using unix, with `-lm`?

```
gcc /path/to/file.c -lm -o /path/to/outputfile
```

Also, you cannot have line breaks in string literals. This isn't allowed:

```
char *MyString = "Hello

World";
```

On top of that, you are trying to call `initial_POPULATION` (int) as if it were a function:

```
initial_POPULATION(pow(1+growth_RATE),time_INTERVAL)
```

Maybe you meant:

```
initial_POPULATION*(pow(1+growth_RATE),time_INTERVAL)
```

And lastly, `time_INTERVAL` is uninitialized, as brought up by @Z4-tier.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the help. I have made the advised changes plus the correction, and now the program does compile, but when I run the program i get  -1.#INF00 as a result.